# A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks, why this happens

Tags: java, android

02-11 23:03:34.679 5179-5187/com.teyaar E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:317)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:212)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1322)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1410)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:131)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:484)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:468)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:410)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:532)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
        at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.seekTo(MediaHTTPConnection.java:463)
        at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.readAt(MediaHTTPConnection.java:722)
        at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.native_readAt(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.readAt(MediaHTTPConnection.java:710)
        at android.media.IMediaHTTPConnection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaHTTPConnection.java:72)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)

Comment: Add some code of your project to help you in better way.

Comment: gitlab.com/samad.a2solution/teyaarsocial.git .

Answer (score 0):

From the error it sounds like you used some object which expects to be 'closed' eventually, and you never did. If you add some source code it would be easier to suggest which thing it was exactly.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/samad.a2solution/teyaarsocial.git ..can you check the code here

Comment: no, sorry. That's 5k lines of code in one file. Good luck though.

Answer (score 0):

`Closable` have a method `close` which you must call to release the resources associated with the component when you no longer need it.

To look for the leak, you can try `MAT`, I often use it to find memory leaks(static data holding a reference to Activity, etc).